# Adobe Flash Media Encoder and WPF MediaElement

Tags: .net, video, http-live-streaming

I am just investigating posiblity if we can get Adobe Flash Media Encoder media streaming via WPF MediaElement.

Are there any .NET RTMP client open source projects?

Can we do it?

Comment: Do you use Adobe Media Server / Flash Media server or what do you intend to use on the server side?

Comment: @JanPetzold In fact it might be any Mdeia Server that streams with RTMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RTMP protocol was once proprietary but has been [opened by Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/rtmp.html) some time ago. So you might consider using an open source server like [Red5](http://www.red5.org/), it should have full RTMP support now.

For .NET, I have only found this library:

http://www.fluorinefx.com/index.html

I have no experience with .NET so I don't know if that is actually helpful for you. For me it looks like it could fit for your scenario.

If it doesn't work you may consider to stream with Adobe Media Server via HLS ([HTTP Live Streaming](http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/What-Is-.../What-is-HLS-%28HTTP-Live-Streaming%29-78221.aspx)) protocol. On the client side this should work on .NET, but again my knowledge of the platform is too limited.

To give you another option you may consider using [Wowza streaming server](http://www.wowza.com/addons/wowza-transcoder-addon) since it provides an add-on that essentially converts an RTMP stream to Microsoft Smooth Streaming (or any other format of your choice) which will definitely be compatible with .NET/Silverlight. If it is smart it shouldn't actually re-encode the bitstream (just re-package it) but I have not tried that.

Comment: Well... Thank your for your input anyway!

Comment: So did you try some of the things I mentioned or what is missing?